# Regular expressions: letter not followed by another letter

Tags: php, regex

I need to watch any word containing the letter `'q'` but the q can not be followed immediately by a  `'u'`. For example it should only match 
`'qwe' out of: queen qwe.`

I am looking for a simple solution, I don't think [q] and excluding r would be tidy.

Comment: Hi there. With this question (and your others on regexs) we generally like to see people make an attempt at answering first - such is the culture here! This will help you become more self-sufficient, so it's a good thing imo. I can recommend [this website](http://regex101.com/) if you'd like to practice - there's a helpful hints box at the bottom, too.

Comment: "Containing" or "Starting with"? Also, please define "word" - what do you want to match in `Iraq's new leadership`? Just to make sure...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would use some word boundaries and a negative lookahead:

```
(\b[^ ]*?q(?!u).*?\b)
```

The `(?!u)` makes sure that there isn't a `u` after the `q`. The `\b[^ ]*?` before and `.*?\b` after will capture the rest of the word.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KV8k6/3/)

Comment: sorry but this matches two words and doesn't separate them

Comment: @JonathanRiekie No it doesn't... see the fiddle

Comment: Yes, it does. Try it on `Iraqi desert`. It will match `qi desert`.

Comment: but if I had: quest qeek omq. It is any word that contains a q not followed by a u. Surely omq should meet this?

Comment: You should use \w instead of '.'

Comment: @TimPietzcker That is the intended behavior, correct?

Comment: @TimPietzcker That is close but it only matches the q in omq not the whole word?

Comment: @JonathanRiekie Oh, that's what you want. Ok, I will fix it

Comment: It's not very elegant, though. The first `?` is superfluous. And it would allow words that contain `qu` to match, if they also contain a `q` without `u`. Not that there are many words like this :) (Imagine a company called `Aquatiq` or a nonsense-adjective like `quasi-Iraqi`)...

Answer (score 1):

You can match q, then "not u":

```
q[^u]
```

Comment: What about `n o p q`? It wouldn't match

Comment: Good point. Your solution will work better.

Comment: It is right but you should use \w* after your current regex and \b before it..

Comment: now it matches `qasqua`.... And it doesn't match `Iraqi`

Comment: No, it still doesn't match a q at the end of the string. Doorknob's solution is better.

Comment: Sorry for editing the ans.wanted to make it more useful